# How to debug an empty cache_page table

Tags: 7, caching, debugging

I have a bunch of sites built off the same profile, and recently noticed the pages aren't being cached. I spent some time doing the usual: looking for `drupal_set_message` calls, disabling all the modules that might disable page cache, as defined [here](https://2bits.com/articles/beware-drupal-modules-disable-page-cache.html). I've also dug into `drupal_page_get_cache`. This lead me to the database, where it turns out the `cache_page` table is empty.

This is clearly the source of the issue, I'm just not sure how/what is preventing the page cache. What I'd like to do is to figure out where page cache is writing to the database, and do a debug_backtrace, or just `dpm` from that point backward.

A) Is there a point in drupal core where cache_page is written to?
B) Any other ideas for debuggings this? (please don't say disable all modules, then re-enable, we have upwards of 200 modules in place with a dozen custom module with interdependencies)

After posting this I opened my IDE and realized I had found the `DrupalDatabaseCache->set` method, and that the `cache_page` `$cid` is never called into that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a page is cacheable is determined by [drupal_page_is_cacheable()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_page_is_cacheable/7.x).

Set a breakpoint there and dig into call stack / step through the conditions to determine the reason why nothing is saved to the `cache_page` bin.

Also take a look at [drupal_page_footer()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_page_footer/7.x) which calls into [drupal_page_set_cache()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_page_set_cache/7.x) in order to store the built page in the page cache.